# Jboss application installation error

Tags: java, deployment, jboss

Currently while deploying the application in Jboss AS (Jboss 6.2) i am facing the below exception.

```
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery) Exception in thread "Periodic Recovery" java.lang.StackOverflowError [Server:server-one] 
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery)     at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:183) [Server:server-one] 
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [Server:server-one] 
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery)     at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:183) [Server:server-one] 
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery)     at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:249) [Server:server-one] 
[Server:server-one] 20:23:35,791 ERROR [stderr] (Periodic Recovery)     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getPermission(FileURLConnection.java:200)
```

Anyone who has face such problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "StackOverflowError" error can be thrown when you define a recursive method and you invoke this method recursively. That means method calls itself. The recursion ends once we invoke the method, passing 0 as a parameter.  In your case  the recursion desn't get terminate. Depending on the JVM’s initial configuration, the results may differ, but eventually the StackOverflowError shall be thrown.

Comment: The simplest solution is to carefully inspect the stack trace and detect the repeating pattern of line numbers. These line numbers indicate the code being recursively called. Once you detect these lines, you must carefully inspect your code and understand why the recursion never terminates.

Comment: If you have verified that the recursion is implemented correctly, you can increase the stack’s size, in order to allow a larger number of invocations. Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB, or 1MB. You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag. This flag can be specified either via the project’s configuration, or via the command line. The format of the -Xss argument is:
-Xss<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]

Answer (score 0):

Root cause:

The amount of stack space required by the program exceeds (than JVM allocated size) for the following reasons:

- The program and/or use-case requires a larger stack (e.g., graphics-intensive programs).
- The application is deeply-nested (recursion).
- Infinite loops

Increase the thread stack size by increments of 64k until the StackOverflowError disappears. Alternative, modify the code or configuration(s) to avoid recursion or infinite loops.